# Replicating rows based on index multiplies the rows instead of replicating

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replication

I have dataframe, where i would like to replicate few rows:

```
         X      Y       diff        No
Index                              
1d       0.000   0.017  0.000e+00   0
2D       0.083   0.017  3.000e-03   1
3D       0.250   0.017  7.200e-03   2
6D       0.500   0.019  2.400e-03   3
1DD      1.000   0.020  2.400e-03   4
2DD      2.000   0.023  1.300e-03   5
3DD      3.000   0.024  1.000e-03   6
5DD      5.000   0.026  6.500e-04   7
7DD      7.000   0.027  2.667e-04   8
10DD     10.000  0.028  1.200e-04   9
20DD     20.000  0.029  1.200e-04   10
30DD     30.000  0.031  0.000e+00   11
```

I want to replicate 30DD 30 times and 20DD 20 times and 10DD 10 times with same index name.

I tried this, instead of replicating it multiplies

```
for i in range(4):
    test1 = df.append(df.ix['30DD']*30)

      X      Y       diff        No
Index                              
1d       0.000   0.017  0.000e+00   0
2D       0.083   0.017  3.000e-03   1
3D       0.250   0.017  7.200e-03   2
6D       0.500   0.019  2.400e-03   3
1DD      1.000   0.020  2.400e-03   4
2DD      2.000   0.023  1.300e-03   5
3DD      3.000   0.024  1.000e-03   6
5DD      5.000   0.026  6.500e-04   7
7DD      7.000   0.027  2.667e-04   8
10DD     10.000  0.028  1.200e-04   9
20DD     20.000  0.029  1.200e-04   10
30DD     30.000  0.031  0.000e+00   11
30DD     900     0.918  0           330
```

Comment: Side note: `ix` has now been deprecated. Use `loc` or `iloc` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new rows, but subtract 1, because [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to original `DataFrame`:

```
vals = ['30DD'] * 29 + ['20DD'] * 19 + ['10DD'] * 9
df = df.append(df.loc[vals])
```

Last if want sorting values by numbers of index values:

```
df = df.iloc[df.index.str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int).squeeze().argsort()]
```

Comment: Yes . I wanted 9 rows , 19 rows and 9 rows to be added as I have already one. This is correct

Answer (score 0):

Using [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), you can create a list of indices for rows you wish to append. Then feed to [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and append to your original dataframe.

```
vals = ['30DD', '20DD', '10DD']
counts = [30, 20, 10]

df = df.append(df.loc[np.repeat(vals, counts)])
```

Comment: Not clear to me. But, more importantly, I think OP can figure out how to subtract one.

Comment: be free correct it, or there is some problem with it?